# R: Adding a title to a ggplot stored in a column of a tibble, based on another column

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tibble

I have a nested tibble that stores data, a grouping variable and a plot illustrating the data.

Consider the following example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

test <- tibble(x=c(1,2), p=list(qplot(1), qplot(2)))
```

Column `p` are the plots, column `x` is the grouping variable.
I would like to provide a title to each plot, based on the value of `x` in the respective row.

I tried using dplyr's mutate function:

```
mutate(test, p=p+labs(title=paste("Group:", x)))
```

However, this specific code fails with `Error: non-numeric argument to binary operator`.

How can I add another layer to the stored ggplots within the tibble?

Comment: Try `test$p <- lapply(1:length(test$p), function(k) test$p[[k]]+labs(title=paste("Group:", test$x[k])))`

Comment: That worked. I tried using lapply on test$p before, but couldn't get it to run. lapply using 1:length does the job. Thank you!